# Symbolication problems in debugging an app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, debugging, core-graphics, exc-bad-access

I'm stuck again with a significantly harder problem than the last time I came here with a crash report. Generally I have no problems whatsoever getting at least to the source of a crash and fixing it but this time I'm having a bit more trouble.

Here's the deal, this crash happens right at launch every time it occurs and it occurs sporadically. The problem is, it **never** happens in the debugger. If I run the copy that was installed during debugging my tapping the icon on the springboard while disconnected from Xcode, I can reproduce it nearly every time. My beta testers have flooded me with copies of this log but there isn't anything I can do because when it symbolicates, I just get a very vague result, pasted below. Does anyone have a means to get to the bottom of a crash that doesn't symbolicate and doesn't occur in the debugger? It definitely seems to be something related to CoreGraphics but I have no clue what class or line to inspect.

```
    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000004
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreGraphics                    0x0002b730 color_space_state_equal + 36
1   CoreGraphics                    0x00008e80 CGColorSpaceEqualToColorSpace + 36
2   CoreGraphics                    0x0009a6cc CGImageCreateWithMaskAndMatte + 180
3   CoreGraphics                    0x0009a758 CGImageCreateWithMask + 4
4   On Deck                         0x00022b3e 0x1000 + 138046
5   UIKit                           0x000159fe -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 258
6   QuartzCore                      0x00014fa6 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 86
7   QuartzCore                      0x00014d24 backing_callback(CGContext*, void*) + 32
8   QuartzCore                      0x00014776 CABackingStoreUpdate + 1226
9   QuartzCore                      0x00014178 -[CALayer _display] + 724
10  QuartzCore                      0x00013e86 -[CALayer display] + 134
11  QuartzCore                      0x00008706 CALayerDisplayIfNeeded + 178
12  QuartzCore                      0x000081c6 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 214
13  QuartzCore                      0x00007fd0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 184
14  QuartzCore                      0x00013df8 CA::Transaction::flush() + 40
15  QuartzCore                      0x00013dc6 +[CATransaction flush] + 22
16  UIKit                           0x0004491c -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 24
17  UIKit                           0x0002fc1c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 456
18  UIKit                           0x000047d0 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1108
19  UIKit                           0x0000420e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
20  On Deck                         0x000b574a 0x1000 + 739146
21  UIKit                           0x00003c4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
22  GraphicsServices                0x318b6e70 0x318b2000 + 20080
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00075a90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00077838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00078606 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
26  CoreFoundation                  0x00008ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
27  CoreFoundation                  0x00008dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
28  UIKit                           0x0002ed42 -[UIApplication _run] + 366
29  UIKit                           0x0002c800 UIApplicationMain + 664
30  On Deck                         0x00002478 0x1000 + 5240
31  On Deck                         0x000023a4 0x1000 + 5028

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.mobileipod.background_load
Thread 1:
0   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00016dc8 sqlite3_extended_errcode + 16868
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00017380 sqlite3_extended_errcode + 18332
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0002a0f8 sqlite3_column_bytes16 + 4328
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000439e0 sqlite3_open16 + 36576
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00002954 sqlite3_step + 56
5   MusicLibrary                    0x316ce5e0 0x316c9000 + 21984
6   MusicLibrary                    0x316ce5bc 0x316c9000 + 21948
7   MusicLibrary                    0x3170891c 0x316c9000 + 260380
8   MusicLibrary                    0x31704fb2 0x316c9000 + 245682
9   MusicLibrary                    0x316cb802 0x316c9000 + 10242
10  MusicLibrary                    0x316cb774 0x316c9000 + 10100
11  MusicLibrary                    0x316d40b0 0x316c9000 + 45232
12  MusicLibrary                    0x316d3fc2 0x316c9000 + 44994
13  MusicLibrary                    0x316d9c46 0x316c9000 + 68678
14  MusicLibrary                    0x316da7fe 0x316c9000 + 71678
15  MusicLibrary                    0x316d3698 0x316c9000 + 42648
16  MediaPlayer                     0x0008b9d0 __-[MPMediaLibraryDataProviderML3 _loadEntitiesUsingFetchRequest:entityQuery:writeBlock:]_block_invoke_1 + 160
17  MediaPlayer                     0x000884d4 __-[MPMediaLibraryDataProviderML3 performTransactionWithBlock:]_block_invoke_1 + 8
18  MusicLibrary                    0x317022da 0x316c9000 + 234202
19  MusicLibrary                    0x317024a8 0x316c9000 + 234664
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007646 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 26
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007986 dispatch_barrier_sync_f$VARIANT$up + 70
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007a12 dispatch_sync_f$VARIANT$up + 22
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007ae8 dispatch_sync$VARIANT$up + 20
24  MusicLibrary                    0x316cb82a 0x316c9000 + 10282
25  MusicLibrary                    0x316d3532 0x316c9000 + 42290
26  MediaPlayer                     0x0008b210 -[MPMediaLibraryDataProviderML3 performTransactionWithBlock:] + 76
27  MediaPlayer                     0x0008acbc -[MPMediaLibraryDataProviderML3 _loadEntitiesUsingFetchRequest:entityQuery:writeBlock:] + 128
28  MediaPlayer                     0x00089b5a __-[MPMediaLibraryDataProviderML3 loadItemsUsingFetchRequest:]_block_invoke_1 + 58
29  MediaPlayer                     0x0008c45a -[MPMediaLibraryDataProviderML3 _performBackgroundTaskWithBlock:] + 142
30  MediaPlayer                     0x00089b04 -[MPMediaLibraryDataProviderML3 loadItemsUsingFetchRequest:] + 48
31  MediaPlayer                     0x00082d9e __-[MPMediaEntityStreamArray _onQueueStartLoadingEntities]_block_invoke_1 + 26
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000b8e0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 4
33  libdispatch.dylib               0x00006626 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 246
34  libsystem_c.dylib               0x0003458a _pthread_wqthread + 258
35  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00034bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00012fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00006032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000703a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000065ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0003458a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00034bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000fc50 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000ff6e semaphore_wait + 2
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000084b2 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 62
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000857e dispatch_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$up + 34
4   MediaPlayer                     0x00088468 -[MPMediaEntityStreamArray count] + 128
5   On Deck                         0x00023f5a 0x1000 + 143194
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000a179c __invoking___ + 60
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00019436 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 102
8   Foundation                      0x0007d438 -[NSInvocationOperation main] + 72
9   Foundation                      0x00016d14 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 652
10  Foundation                      0x00016a78 -[NSOperation start] + 16
11  Foundation                      0x0007cec4 ____startOperations_block_invoke_2 + 40
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000b8e0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 4
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00006626 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 246
14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x0003458a _pthread_wqthread + 258
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00034bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000fc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000f758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000762b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00078562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00008ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00008dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x0000627e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0003330a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00034bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00011d18 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0005a860 _pthread_cond_wait + 756
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00001eb2 pthread_cond_wait + 26
3   CoreMedia                       0x32d7a8f4 0x32d78000 + 10484
4   CoreMedia                       0x32d7a83a 0x32d78000 + 10298
5   MediaToolbox                    0x00003a64 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 48
6   CoreMedia                       0x32d984dc 0x32d78000 + 132316
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0003330a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00034bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000123ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000346d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00034bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x002697e0    r1: 0x002aa860      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00255880    r5: 0x00251cd0      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x2fdfcca8
    r8: 0x002aa8a0    r9: 0x002fc0a0     r10: 0x33b4319c     r11: 0x0026d1b0
    ip: 0x3fe5c2e8    sp: 0x2fdfcca8      lr: 0x32a06e87      pc: 0x32a29730
  cpsr: 0x60000030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0xe5fff +On Deck armv7  <fcdc25df229038b698dc1669dbff7924> /var/mobile/Applications/263C5EAC-E18C-4894-9DF2-1722DE47EDC7/On Deck.app/On Deck
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x31014000 - 0x31019fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3102c000 - 0x3105ffff  QuickLook armv7  <29d2d981d1d6358381f5716ee37314b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3106b000 - 0x3106efff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x31071000 - 0x31135fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x31139000 - 0x3113cfff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3113d000 - 0x31245fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x31282000 - 0x312a2fff  MobileSync armv7  <4df400c4559435889eccd88db77a110c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x312a3000 - 0x312a6fff  ActorKit armv7  <f7aa6cdd654231988aafcf448978f450> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x312a7000 - 0x312acfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x312db000 - 0x3130efff  StoreServices armv7  <d526715648f435c3aac4c42953e76d20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x3132b000 - 0x3143dfff  MediaPlayer armv7  <da848c0745a637af81d7edd962a09324> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x314e5000 - 0x3151cfff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x31547000 - 0x31570fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x31600000 - 0x31603fff  CertUI armv7  <9060fe03a4943ef295531feced9a17dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x3165c000 - 0x316a6fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x316ab000 - 0x316c8fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x316c9000 - 0x3178ffff  MusicLibrary armv7  <71a09022bd8b3b6a90a250199d190f10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x31790000 - 0x317befff  DataAccess armv7  <3a2e67aa1d8834b7a8fc2fbb56654b15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x317bf000 - 0x317c9fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x317ca000 - 0x317d9fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <563a09bcdb2f32369b1e22f53f58273a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x317da000 - 0x31883fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x318ac000 - 0x318b1fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x318b2000 - 0x318befff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x318bf000 - 0x318c5fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x318cc000 - 0x318cdfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x318d7000 - 0x319f1fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x319f2000 - 0x31a0bfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x31a0c000 - 0x31abbfff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x31ac7000 - 0x31acafff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x31acb000 - 0x31ad0fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x31ad1000 - 0x31adafff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x31adb000 - 0x31b1dfff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31be6000 - 0x31c14fff  MIME armv7  <60de1fe0bbb134d788c09f7c34b1caa4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x31c78000 - 0x31c7ffff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x31dc1000 - 0x31dc8fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x31dcd000 - 0x31ebafff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x31ebb000 - 0x31efefff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f790c26852cb3cf298abe56bc9a3940b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x323e5000 - 0x323e5fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x324b2000 - 0x324b6fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x324b7000 - 0x324dbfff  MediaControl armv7  <1cfc7d79f554357ab59eb69f9efebf07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl
0x32620000 - 0x32629fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x32649000 - 0x32795fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <482b13059e8a329fa5d832baede25103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x327dc000 - 0x327dffff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3282f000 - 0x328b3fff  AVFoundation armv7  <eeaf5f4f822436a5bd1655f536e69879> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x328e7000 - 0x32935fff  CoreMotion armv7  <58c353bb7e33361f881da07c72f4cdfb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x32957000 - 0x32980fff  ContentIndex armv7  <ecd71782cd833360872b943ecc65d203> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x32981000 - 0x32982fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3299e000 - 0x329fdfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x329fe000 - 0x32b1ffff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32b6f000 - 0x32b86fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x32bd1000 - 0x32bf0fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x32c68000 - 0x32cb6fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x32cb7000 - 0x32cebfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <570c63dc3a273a5a8c9072fd5567f5c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32cf8000 - 0x32d30fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x32d3f000 - 0x32d41fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32d42000 - 0x32d4ffff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x32d59000 - 0x32d5afff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x32d6c000 - 0x32d72fff  IAP armv7  <c0f4c99a1b493e489948f231ad9238e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x32d78000 - 0x32db8fff  CoreMedia armv7  <8e0570582ba535bfa74f1f00eef64376> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x32eb8000 - 0x32ebafff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <9e7efa009730322f84bbc5d8bf1ded94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32ee3000 - 0x32ee5fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x32ee6000 - 0x32eeafff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x32efe000 - 0x32efefff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x33281000 - 0x332c8fff  MessageUI armv7  <35a81f5d4eb03467a1447db80337e570> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x332cb000 - 0x332cefff  ArtworkCache armv7  <4863e321afee3ac5a3749e50cd926597> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x33355000 - 0x33356fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x33379000 - 0x33379fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3367d000 - 0x33680fff  MediaRemote armv7  <0804293b2774359189f3a67e2c81558d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x33681000 - 0x336b4fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x336df000 - 0x33734fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x33751000 - 0x33855fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33857000 - 0x33be4fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33ca4000 - 0x33d39fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33d3a000 - 0x33d4cfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <659ea9d5b13d3fefb37acff09016a69c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x33d4d000 - 0x33d7cfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x33d7d000 - 0x33dbcfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33dcd000 - 0x33dd2fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x33dd3000 - 0x33e0bfff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x33e0d000 - 0x33e23fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x33e40000 - 0x33e48fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x33f7d000 - 0x33f8bfff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x33fd0000 - 0x33fdcfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33fdd000 - 0x33fedfff  WebBookmarks armv7  <6956561235333e74b8ff316cb2edc93e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x33fee000 - 0x34034fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x34037000 - 0x34037fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3403d000 - 0x340e3fff  Celestial armv7  <7fbd02fa664b33babaf0327c320d1491> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x340e8000 - 0x3412efff  CoreLocation armv7  <c1924042951e3df98515c7bf36093c1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x34146000 - 0x34433fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x3444b000 - 0x3445afff  Notes armv7  <d9c976ca976e3d029f69febd48f17601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x3445b000 - 0x34462fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34463000 - 0x34470fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34471000 - 0x34477fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x34478000 - 0x34597fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x361bb000 - 0x361bbfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x362c2000 - 0x362e2fff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x362e3000 - 0x3636dfff  Message armv7  <2cce1aa95a493906bb0227197f9e4b96> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x36395000 - 0x36404fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x36405000 - 0x364b6fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x364b9000 - 0x36556fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x36557000 - 0x36562fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3664a000 - 0x3664bfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3664c000 - 0x3664efff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x36712000 - 0x367d1fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x367df000 - 0x367e1fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x367e3000 - 0x3683cfff  EventKit armv7  <0d4e597ee229337183e96e921a72e30a> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x36845000 - 0x36882fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x36885000 - 0x369d9fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x369da000 - 0x36a2bfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x36ab9000 - 0x36b9efff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x36ba4000 - 0x36bb4fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36bbe000 - 0x36bd3fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x36bdd000 - 0x36c12fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x36c61000 - 0x36c74fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x36c75000 - 0x36c77fff  MailServices armv7  <74ae0145ef713c6d91fd8f68885b0a61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x36c7c000 - 0x36caffff  iCalendar armv7  <34ce1957082f3518b5740ac33cfc92eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x36cc7000 - 0x36d48fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x36d7d000 - 0x36d86fff  ITSync armv7  <ba8b48d061903e4096774344448776d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x36d87000 - 0x36d8bfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x36d8c000 - 0x37397fff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x37450000 - 0x3748cfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x3752f000 - 0x3754ffff  AppleAccount armv7  <4e0ac5cf93b338ab8c5f34ba3c5e2ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x3756c000 - 0x37578fff  HomeSharing armv7  <2df6957cdfea31aea12eebf27ca1691c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x3757f000 - 0x37580fff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to symbolicate the crash log with a wrong symbolic file. None of the items on the stack that comes from your app are symbolicated.

Make sure you keep a copy of all the versions you have shippe. Otherwise it will be impossible to symbolicate them.

Comment: I have all versions archived in Xcode, there should be no problems symbolicating. All dSYMs are intact.

Answer (score 0):

Some new symbols in iOS 7 related to new functionality might not be present in the DSYMs for frameworks like UIKit.

There is a bug in CGColorSpaceEqualToColorSpace that gets called when setting the stroke or fill color with the CGContextSet... methods. There an EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurring if the color is set like that on a background thread, e.g. for drawing a tile in CATiledLayer.

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

The workaround I found is to use UIKit methods for setting the color, e.g.

```
[[UIColor blackColor] set]
```

I'm just about going to build a small sample to go with **rdar://14684188**